# Intellij Maven Indexing Error. Happening on Windows 10

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I keep getting this error on intelliJ 2020.3.

I have tried:

1. Invalidating cache
2. Updating indexes
3. Downgrading from the 2021 distro
   Deleted the .idea directory and re-imported the project. Any leads will be appreciated.

[image: intellij screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and running "Reload" from Maven tool window?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: nope, not behind a proxy @Renis1235